# Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

While I try to deploy UWP blank project also in my windows 10 phone, I get the deployment error as follow.

[image]

In the configuration manager also it has been configured correctly.

[image]

There are no any extensions and nugget packages added in the solution.

Comment: How are you trying to deploy the application package? How is the device connected to your development machine?

Comment: When deploy apps on phone, you will need to make sure your phone is not in the lock screen.

Comment: I deployed using ctrl+f5 as well as by the deployment option. device is connected by USB and USB service is running. and also screen is also unlocked. I guess there is phone deployment problems in Visual studio.